# How to save data in php results executed by a .php page?

Tags: php, facebook

I need to know how to save data executed by a php page..Like this.

http://www.facebook.com/ajax/typeahead_friends.php?&__a=1

Above link shows current facebook user's friends list (name,user id)
So i want to get them and save them? How to save friends user ids' to my datbase?

Answer (score 0):

Doing so is against Facebook's terms and conditions and also won't work due to the browser security model- you should be using the API to retrieve data

For example, to get a list of friends, you can make a call to the `/{user id}/friends` connection in the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

Comment: yeah i got a token access? but do you know how to save them? name and the User Id?
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=AAAAAAITEghMBALoSupr9EsypSOjL1Mbt4K0T428yGZAhfOt63BtM4nmDdYivkLda6e0KbLrtPYpohHLOMcRj86eTF9wkv27h1dBElFwF4gO3c3U6ZA

Answer (score 0):

The result of the call looks like a simple JSON except for "for (;;);" at the beginning. If you strip those characters, you should be able to use a serializer that convers json to language hash ( based on what you use )

### eg in python

```
import json
resulting_fiends_txt = '<put the text after you have removed for (;;);'   
friends = json.loads(resulting_frields_txt)['payload']['friends']
for f in friends:
    print "ID: %s, Name: %s" % (f['i'], f['t'])
```

once you have access to those fields, you can save it anyway you like.