# How to save data in php results?

Tags: php, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to save data in php results executed by a .php page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920081/how-to-save-data-in-php-results-executed-by-a-php-page)

I need to know how to save data execcuted by a php page

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=myAccessToken
```

This shows the current Facebook user's friends list (name,user id).

I want to get and save the friends user IDs to my database. How can this be done?

Comment: Do not publish access token !

Comment: Sry! I'm new..thanks for advice.. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Just connect do database

```
<?php
include 'db_connect.php';
```

Get friends

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=myAccessToken'), true);
```

and insert them into database

```
foreach($json['data'] as $friend){
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO friends(id, name) VALUES (".$friend['id'].", '".mysql_real_escape_string($friend['name'])."');");
}
```

so after all, it could look like

```
<?php
include 'db_connect.php';
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=myAccessToken'), true);
foreach($json['data'] as $friend){
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO friends(id, name) VALUES (".$friend['id'].", '".mysql_real_escape_string($friend['name'])."');");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd get the content with `file_get_contents()`, then `json_decode()` that content, then loop through the array to save to your database.